# D3js chart not rendering correctly on client, D3 source code stored on server

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, windows-server-2008

I have a system in place whereby a D3js chart is generated from an external JSON file. All is well on my development server machine & the chart is displayed on the client side.

I have now moved the files to a live server, windows 2008 r2, and I have run into trouble. The background SVG element is displayed but none of the overlying elements are, such as axis and bars representing the data.

Notes: JavaScript is not disabled on client. The values in the dataset are just placeholders, the actual values are determined by the json.data file.

Has anyone run into a similar issue?
     Check out this link where you can view the files:[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/94h21kUA6IBdo0acK0rr?p=preview)

index.html

```
<script>
    var data = [
        {key: "desiccant_1",      value: 17},
        {key: "desiccant_2",            value: 9 },
        {key: "desiccant_3",       value: 8 },
        {key: "desiccant_4",        value: 12 },
        {key: "desiccant_5",          value: 10 },
        {key: "desiccant_6",            value: 7 },
        {key: "laser_1",           value: 12 },
        {key: "laser_2",           value: 10 },
        {key: "laser_3",                   value: 10 },
        {key: "laser_4",               value: 11 },
        {key: "laser_5",                 value: 9 },
        {key: "laser_6",  value: 13},
        {key: "table_top_1",           value: 10},
        {key: "table_top_2",           value: 11},
        {key: "RMI",             value: 12},
        {key: "Miscellaneous",       value: 12}
    ];
    var w = 800;
    var h = 550;
    var margin = {
        top: 58,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 80,
        right: 40
        };
    var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var threshold = 16.5;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(data.map(function(entry){
        return entry.key;
    }))
        .rangeBands([0, width],.2);
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.value;
    })])
        .range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()   
                  .scale(x)
                  .orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(y)
                  .orient("left");      
    // Second Y Axis
    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(y)
              .orient("right");
    var yGridLines = d3.svg.axis()
                         .scale(y)
                         .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                         .tickFormat("")
                         .orient("left");
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "chart")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
    var chart = svg.append("g")
        .classed("display", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    function plot(params){
    this.append("g")
         .call(yGridLines)
         .classed("gridline", true)
         .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    this.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(params.data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed("bar", true)
        .attr("x", function (d,i){
            return x(d.key);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d,i){
            return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return x.rangeBand();
        });
    this.selectAll(".bar-label")
        .data(params.data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .classed("bar-label", true)
        .attr("x", function(d,i){
            return x(d.key) + (x.rangeBand()/2)
        })
        .attr("dx", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d,i){
            return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("dy", -6)
        .text(function(d){
            return d.value;
        })
    this.append("g")
     .classed("x axis", true)
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", -8)
                .attr("dy" ,8)
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) rotate(-45)");

    this.append("g")
         .classed("y axis", true)
         .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
         .call(yAxis);
    this.select(".y.axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-50," + height/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
        .text("Downtime [Hrs]");


    this.select(".x.axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ",80)")
        .text("[Stations]");    
        // title 
    this.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
        .text("EA/ LW");  
        // limit line 
    this.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", y(threshold))
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", y(threshold))
        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
         .attr("stroke", "yellow");
         // 2nd y 
    this.append("g")
        .classed("y axis", true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis2);  
    }
    d3.json('data.json', function(data) {

    plot.call(chart, {data: data});
});
</script>
```

json.data

```
[
    {
        "key": "desiccant_1",
        "value": "5.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "desiccant_2",
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "desiccant_3",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "desiccant_4",
        "value": "6.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "desiccant_5",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "desiccant_6",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_1",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_2",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_3",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_4",
        "value": "5.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_5",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "laser_6",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "table_top_1",
        "value": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "table_top_2",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "RMI",
        "value": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "key": "Miscellaneous",
        "value": "0.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing on the client when served from your production server?

Comment: This is just it Mark, no errors in the console or anything it simply doesn't display the whole chart. I'm wondering is it the order of the calls in my code the problem but then again it works fine in developent.

Comment: Change your `d3.json` call to `d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error); plot.call(chart, {data: data}); });` and see if any errors are logged.

Comment: Hi Mark I changed the code but no errors or warnings are logged.

Comment: One more thing I noticed, your plunker doesn't use the JSON data to set the domain's of the axis.  I know this doesn't address your problem, but here's a [fixed plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0VSBoQJofUNxfVGvgsh?p=preview) that handles that correctly.  I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: The answer is probably that you're not getting your data returned properly. Have you logged "params.data" to make sure it's an array and it's what you expect it to be?

Comment: I tried to access the JSON file in the browser & I got back a server error 404 - File or directory not found. I can access the other files no problem.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that the .json extension was not configured on the server. I followed the steps at the URL below & all is well once more, thank you all for your input. http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/